# Clarification on reading data from a simple Text file in Java

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream

I'm trying to fetch the data from a text file using **FileInputStream** but it is not happening 
Here is the code.

```
package com.example.ex2;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Input {
public static void main(String args[]){  
      try{  
        FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("abc.txt");  
        int i;  
        FileInputStream fr;
        while((i=fr.read())!=-1)  
         System.out.println((char)i);

        fin.close();  
      }catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }  
     }  
    }
```

The error which i'm getting is : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The local variable fr may not have been initialized
I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: fr is not initialized in your code.  Why you are using the fr,  you have the fin and you can directly read from fin.

Comment: you should be using `fin` not `fr`

Comment: fr = new FileInputStream(Path);

Comment: btw, always close the stream in finally block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first , replace this :

```
 while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
```

with this :

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
```

second thing is that you have to check that your class file name match the Class name, another point is that you have to add `throws Exception` next to the main method.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring `fr` here:

```
FileInputStream fr;
```

But you never initialize it. The you try to use it in

```
while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
```

but as `fr` is not initialized, there is no Object to call `.read()` on, so you get your error.

I guess you want to change your `while` to:

```
while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
```

and remove `fr` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `fr`

```
 while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
```

You can use

```
 FileInputStream fr // initialize this
```

Use

```
  FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream(new File("abc.txt"));
  while((i=fr.read())!=-1)
```

But I think you did some mistake while coding. Then you should write your code as

```
 FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("abc.txt");
 int i;
 while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
     System.out.println((char)i);
 fin.close();
```